# Reading Text File in to Hbase MapReduce and store it to HTable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am new to HBaseMapReduce and Hadoop Data Base. I need to read a raw text file from mapreduce job and store the retrieved data into Htable using HBase MapReduce API.

I am googling from may days but I am not able to understand the extact flow. Can any one please provide me with some sample Code of reading data from A file.

I need to read Data From a Text/csv files. I can find some examples of reading data from command prompt. Which method can we use to read an xml file `FileInputFormat` or, please help me in learning Mapreduce  API and please provide me with simple read and write examples.

Comment: Duplicate question asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246464/read-text-file-from-system-to-hbase-mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

You can import your csv data to HBase using importtsv and completebulkupload tools. importtsv loads csvs to hadoop files and completebulkupload loads them to a specified HTable. You can use these tools both from command line and Java code. If this can help you inform me to provide sample code or command