# Read text file from System to Hbase MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I need to load data from text file to Map Reduce, I have searched the web, but I didn't find any right solution for my work.

Is there any method or class which reads a text /csv file from a system and store the data into HBASE Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading from text file first of all the text file should be in hdfs.
You need to specify input format and outputformat for job

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "example");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("PATH to text file"));
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(YourMapper.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("hbase_table_name", YourReducer.class, job);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

`YourReducer` should extends `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer<Text, Text, Text>`

Sample reducer code

```
public class YourReducer extends TableReducer<Text, Text, Text> {    
private byte[] rawUpdateColumnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("colName");
/**
* Called once at the beginning of the task.
*/
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
// something that need to be done at start of reducer
}

@Override
public void reduce(Text keyin, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
// aggregate counts
int valuesCount = 0;
for (Text val : values) {
   valuesCount += 1;
   // put date in table
   Put put = new Put(keyin.toString().getBytes());
   long explicitTimeInMs = new Date().getTime();
   put.add(rawUpdateColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("colName"), explicitTimeInMs,val.toString().getBytes());
   context.write(keyin, put);


      }
    }
}
```

Sample mapper class

```
public static class YourMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```